# How would I insert the same row with all the different subquery values at the same time, almost like an iteration over the subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE messages (messageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                       , message VARCHAR(150)
                       , sender VARCHAR(40)
                       , recipient VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TABLE employees (employeeid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                        , employeename VARCHAR(40)
                        , area VARCHAR(40))
```

My problem is that I don't know a simple way of inserting a selection of employees from the employees table directly into the messages table like:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message
                      , sender
                      , recipient) 
VALUES ("Message."
        , "System"
        , (SELECT employeename 
           FROM employees 
           WHERE area = "Maintenance"))
```

This returns the error: `Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row` and I'm not sure on how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message, sender, recipient)
    SELECT 'Message.', 'System', employeename
    FROM employees
    WHERE area = 'Maintenance';
```

Note that the `values` keyword is not needed.  I also replaced the double quotes with single quotes, because these are the SQL standard delimiter for strings.

Comment: Interesting to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can not insert into the table `messages` without inserting value for column messageid even if you change the double quotes with single quotes because "**Field 'messageid' doesn't have a default value**". You need to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (messageid
                      , message
                      , sender
                      , recipient) 
VALUES (1
        , 'Message.'
        , 'System'
        , (SELECT employeename 
           FROM employees 
           WHERE area = 'Maintenance'))
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f6430ab1db838cd910f26a45c0af7193)

Other option is to create your table messages  like this:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (messageid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
                       , message VARCHAR(150)
                       , sender VARCHAR(40)
                       , recipient VARCHAR(40))
```

Then your code would work:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message
                      , sender
                      , recipient) 
VALUES ("Message."
        , "System"
        , (SELECT employeename 
           FROM employees 
           WHERE area = "Maintenance"))
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=216f1f73ec1ae0842b9d611ec5b37e14) showing you that example

But your error **Subquery returns more than 1 row** is caused because you have two rows in your table `employees` with value "Maintenance" in the column `area` like you can see in this small demo: [click here to see what causes your error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24aa721846e15b4d53fa8b90f7207d0e)

Now what you need to do is to decide what will you do with this situation. Do you want to insert max or min value from the table `employees` like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message
                      , sender
                      , recipient) 
VALUES ("Message."
        , "System"
        , (SELECT max(employeename)
           FROM employees 
           WHERE area = "Maintenance"))
```

Or maybe you want to add one more criteria to the select statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message
                      , sender
                      , recipient) 
VALUES ("Message."
        , "System"
        , (SELECT employeename
           FROM employees 
           WHERE area = "Maintenance"
           and employeeid = 1))
```

Both of this examples work, [check it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62d1385d9a025c808e7d9633b33a364d), but it is up to you what do you want to insert.

Comment: Thanks for the detail in your answer. I learned a lot from this!

Comment: Hi @prudence70, You are welcome. I am happy to help. Have you seen the part where I explain why do you get the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row` ? I ask because the answer you selected as correct, in my opinion, does not solve your problem ?